# Perl: see if function returns successfully

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have a perl script that runs at 20 threads. I have a function that will occasionally fail and return

```
Thread 15 terminated abnormally: No elements found for form number 1 at FILENAME.pl line 40 thread 15.
```

The reason for this is because I run `$mech->form_number(1)` and there is no form_number(1) most likely because the page did not finish loading.

How would I check to see if $mech->form_number(1) returned successfully?

I tried doing `next if(!$mech->form_number(1));` but this did not work.

Comment: 1) Oh god, why are you using threads in Perl? 2) It's throwing an exception.

Comment: and you catch exceptions using http://p3rl.org/eval (in its eval BLOCK form)

Comment: are your threads all trying to share the same WWW::Mechanize object?

Comment: Each WWW::Mechanize::Firefox object is created in each thread. It's just that sometimes the element I am looking for is not done loading at that point yet (I add a sleep between form fill)

Comment: Nowt wrong with perl threads if used appropriately. Of course, they often aren't.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with perl threads, that's why first implementation (Thread.pm) was removed and the second (ithreads) are offcially discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first check that your page has forms by running:

```
next unless scalar @{ $mech->forms };
```